# how do I generate preview image based on first page of a PDF or PPT/PPTX or DOC/DOCX in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, ms-word, preview

I have read all references and haven't found a solution on it.

Is there any 3rd-party component in .NET available for doing such a job?  such as converting documents (doc, pdf, ppt, xls....) into images?

thank you very much and I'm waiting online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [ImageGlue](http://www.websupergoo.com/imageglue-1.htm).
As for the MS Office formats, I think the files need to have the thumbnail option enabled for ImageGlue to get the preview image.

My company implements a Digital Asset Management system that uses ImageGlue to generate preview images for a lot of different file formats, so it should definitely do the trick.